# Can xampp be used as a full server?

Tags: xampp, local, host, dedicated

I want to use xampp as a server (not local server but more like a server with a dedicated ip.) Can xampp be used for a server besides local? Maybe I'm just thinking backwards.

Comment: If you're getting a dedicated server (particularly a unix/linux one), then you should probably use the packages provided by the server's distribution. I can't think of any "big" distros that DON'T provide a complete LAMP-type stack, even if it's not in a single convenient installer the way it is with xampp.

Answer (score 0):

If You have Windows server, it is good option but if You are on Linux, it's not the best idea.